# How to negate a number using shift operator

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I need to negate a number using shift operator. 
Example:
If number = 5 then negation of 5 should be -5
If number =-5 then negation of -5 should be 5.

Comment: You can't do it with the shifting operator(s) only.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Given that there are only 31 possible shifts for an int, this shouldn't take too long to figure out by experimentation?

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

Not with the shiftoperator but there is other bitwise operator using them you can do this

```
    int i  = 10;
    i = (~i)+1;
    System.out.println(i);
    i = (~i)+1;
    System.out.println(i);
    i = (~i)+1;
    System.out.println(i);
    i = (~i)+1;
    System.out.println(i);
```

result

```
-10
10
-10
10
```

BTW it is example of Two's complement and used for binary signed number representations